# was there a word "hat" to go with what and that?

Tags: etymology

I know there are
th wh and h triplets in English for 
here, hither, hence and used to be for hen (when, then) so was wondering for what and that.

Thanks

Comment: What has your research turned up?

Comment: I believe you can see one of its shadows in "hat trick"; clearly nothing to do with headgear, which is almost certainly not English "trick" but more likely related to Central/Eastern European forms of "three…" as Czech tři, Polish trzy, Russian три  - all pronounced like "tree."

English "hat trick" for "three in a row/of a kind" must be taken as read with no supporting evidence. If some once-prevalent combination of more-ancient, more-Eastern tongues translated into early English - even British - as "that trio / those three" and came down to us sounded as "hat trick" it would make sense.